# rightBarButtonItem seems to stack when moving from one viewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rightbarbuttonitem

My problem is that I have created a `rightBarButtonItem` for each view in my storyboard, the `rightBarButtonItem` in my app is supposed to keep track of the total cost of the items the user has added to their shopping list. In my `viewDidLoad` on the first `ViewController` I set the `rightBarButtonItem's` customView to a `UILabel`. When moving to another `ViewController` I set that ViewController's `rightBarButtonItem` to the one from the previous `ViewController`. However, when I move back to the previous `ViewController` that `ViewController's` `rightBarButtonItem` doesn't change when I try to update it. Instead, it looks like it did when I moved the previous time, if I move to the same ViewController again the first ViewController's `rightBarButtonItem` always seems to be one step behind where it should upon return. In other words, the ViewController's `rightBarButtonItem` seems to stack when moving to another `ViewController`.

Any help is much appreciated.

-- Relevant code:

viewDidLoad - First ViewController

```
double total;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    total = 0;
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", total];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    UILabel *customItem = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];
    [customItem setText:text];
    [customItem setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setCustomView:customItem];
}
```

prepareForSegue - First ViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    OrderViewController *orderViewController = (OrderViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [orderViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setCustomView:_rightBarButtonItem.customView];
}
```

viewWillDisappear - Second ViewController

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
// sendTotalBackFromOrder is delegate method upon returning to first ViewController
    [_delegate sendTotalBackFromOrder:_total];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

sendTotalBackFromOrder - FirstViewController

```
// This is the method where it becomes apparent that rightBarButtonItem is being stacked and is always 'behind' where it should be
- (void)sendTotalBackFromOrder:(double)currTotal{
    total = currTotal;
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", total];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    UILabel *customItem = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];
    [customItem setText:text];
    [customItem setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setCustomView:customItem];
}
```

Comment: is sendTotalBackFromOrder: being called? where the delegate is set?

Comment: can u write the piece of code in viewWillAppear rather than viewDidLoad

Comment: @agy sendTotalBackFromOrder is called when my second ViewController 'disappears'. Delegate is set in the first ViewController's prepareForSegue method, I just forgot to add it in the description.

Comment: @Rajan moving code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear had no effect. I believe the problem is caused by some kind of stack (possibly rightBarButtonItem or navigationItem) upon return from second ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the lines in viewDidLoad and sendTotalBackFromOrder:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setCustomView:customItem];
```

for

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customItem];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barBtn;
```

Comment: Thanks @agy works like a charm. I should have thought of that.